# css with background image without repeating the image

Tags: css, background-image

I have a column (lets assume the width is 40px) and there I have some rows. The height of the rows depends on the length of text (if the text is long then there is a break line and therefore the height increases).

Now I want to display an icon in each row next to the text to show the user for example that he has already completed something in that tab. So I was trying to solve this by using only css. So if the user completes a tab then I change the css of that row. However, I'm not able to add to that row an image without that the image is being repeated.

I'm using this css code:

```
padding: 0 8px;
padding-top: 8px;
padding-right: 8px;
padding-bottom: 8px;
padding-left: 8px;
overflow: hidden;
zoom: 1;
text-align: left;
font-size: 13px;
font-family: "Trebuchet MS",Arial,Sans;
line-height: 24px;
color: black;
border-bottom: solid 1px #BBB;
background-color: white;
background-image: url('images/checked.gif');
background-repeat-x: no-repeat;
background-repeat-y: no-repeat;
```

Does anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Instead of

```
background-repeat-x: no-repeat;
background-repeat-y: no-repeat;
```

which is not correct, use

```
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

Answer (score 28):

```
body {
    background: url(images/image_name.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Here is a good solution to get your image to cover the full area of the web app 
perfectly

Answer (score 6):

Try this

```
padding:8px;
overflow: hidden;
zoom: 1;
text-align: left;
font-size: 13px;
font-family: "Trebuchet MS",Arial,Sans;
line-height: 24px;
color: black;
border-bottom: solid 1px #BBB;
background:url('images/checked.gif') white no-repeat;
```

This is full css.. Why you use `padding:0 8px`, then override it with paddings? This is what you need...

Answer (score 4):

This is all you need:

```
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```